# Sed regex ".*?=" string doesn't replace correct string

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have the following line:
`echo 'var="string"' | sed "s/.*?=/replace=/g"`

Output:
`var="string"`

Expected output:
`replace="string"`

When tested on regex.101, the regex `.*?=` successfully gets the correct part of the string. Why doesn't sed work with this?

Comment: Add `-E` option to `sed`, it's part of extended version.

Comment: No, `-E` won't turn `sed` into Perl, just enable some fairly pedestrian regex extensions. Nongreedy wildcards are not part of ERE.